# Flutter stateful widget import can't find the function

Tags: flutter

Hi my custom button file
buttonn.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:progress_state_button/iconed_button.dart';
import 'package:progress_state_button/progress_button.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Progress Button',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: ProgressButtonHomePage(title: 'Progress Button'),
    );
  }
}

class ProgressButtonHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  ProgressButtonHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _ProgressButtonHomePageState createState() => _ProgressButtonHomePageState();
}

class _ProgressButtonHomePageState extends State<ProgressButtonHomePage> {
  ButtonState stateOnlyText = ButtonState.idle;
  ButtonState stateTextWithIcon = ButtonState.idle;

  Widget buildCustomButton() {
    var progressTextButton = ProgressButton(
      stateWidgets: {
        ButtonState.idle: Text(
          "Idle",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
        ButtonState.loading: Text(
          "Loading",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
        ButtonState.fail: Text(
          "Fail",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
        ButtonState.success: Text(
          "Success",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        )
      },
      stateColors: {
        ButtonState.idle: Colors.grey.shade400,
        ButtonState.loading: Colors.blue.shade300,
        ButtonState.fail: Colors.red.shade300,
        ButtonState.success: Colors.green.shade400,
      },
      onPressed: onPressedCustomButton,
      state: stateOnlyText,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    );
    return progressTextButton;
  }

  Widget buildTextWithIcon() {
    return ProgressButton.icon(iconedButtons: {
      ButtonState.idle: IconedButton(
          text: "Send",
          icon: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.white),
          color: Colors.deepPurple.shade500),
      ButtonState.loading:
          IconedButton(text: "Loading", color: Colors.deepPurple.shade700),
      ButtonState.fail: IconedButton(
          text: "Failed",
          icon: Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.white),
          color: Colors.red.shade300),
      ButtonState.success: IconedButton(
          text: "Success",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.check_circle,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          color: Colors.green.shade400)
    }, onPressed: onPressedIconWithText, state: stateTextWithIcon);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            buildBuildTextWithIcon(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBuildTextWithIcon() => buildTextWithIcon();

  void onPressedCustomButton() {
    setState(() {
      switch (stateOnlyText) {
        case ButtonState.idle:
          stateOnlyText = ButtonState.loading;
          break;
        case ButtonState.loading:
          stateOnlyText = ButtonState.fail;
          break;
        case ButtonState.success:
          stateOnlyText = ButtonState.idle;
          break;
        case ButtonState.fail:
          stateOnlyText = ButtonState.success;
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  void onPressedIconWithText() {
    switch (stateTextWithIcon) {
      case ButtonState.idle:
        stateTextWithIcon = ButtonState.loading;
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          setState(() {
            stateTextWithIcon = Random.secure().nextBool()
                ? ButtonState.success
                : ButtonState.fail;
          });
        });

        break;
      case ButtonState.loading:
        break;
      case ButtonState.success:
        stateTextWithIcon = ButtonState.idle;
        break;
      case ButtonState.fail:
        stateTextWithIcon = ButtonState.idle;
        break;
    }
    setState(() {
      stateTextWithIcon = stateTextWithIcon;
    });
  }
}
```

When I try to use it in main dart it says

The method 'buildTextWithIcon' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'buildTextWithIcon'
How can I import it as widget to use. It's also a pubsec package.

my main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/buttttooon.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(child: buildTextWithIcon()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you mentioned your file named buttonn.dart but your import saids import 'package:flutter_app/buttttooon.dart'; Are you sure you don't have typos? Plus, buildTextWithIcon() is just a method inside ProgressButtonHomePage class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should really try better understanding the fundamentals of structuring your Flutter code before you start building your own widgets. In this code there are a bunch of big structural problems that need to be addressed.

So let me explain some basics to make your code run the way you want to:

- The main.dart file should only contain the main() method that executes `runApp(MyApp());` and imports your my_app.dart.
- So consequentially you should create a separate dart file for the MyApp class where you can set the title, theme and a home widget that should also be stored in a separate file.
- In this home screen you can create its layout. In your case this could look something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter_app/progress_button.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),)
      body: Center(child: ProgressButton()),
    );
  }
}
```

- To create your progress button you create a new dart file and create the `StatefulWidget` CustomButton. This should look something like this:

```
class ProgressButtonHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  ProgressButtonHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _ProgressButtonHomePageState createState() => _ProgressButtonHomePageState();
}

class _ProgressButtonHomePageState extends State<ProgressButtonHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(); //replace the [Container] with your progress button
  }
}
```

One point I definitely want to address here in addition is that you never ever should use the `main()` function twice. The only time it should be called is in your main.dart file.

I hope this should help. The reason why it did not work is because the `buildBuildTextWithIcon()` method was located inside the private _ProgressButtonHomePageState class (private because of the underscore). But it would not have worked anyway because of all the other issues that I have pointed out previously.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You probably made a change to **framework.dart** by mistake.
(I am using vscode)

Step 1:

Go framework.dart (You can go to the StatefullWidget by left-clicking the shortcut.)

Step 2:
To see the changes, click the "**see changes**" button from the top right buttons and update to original.

worked for me